# find maximum weight edge connected to any specific node in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

```
MATCH (d:domain) 
WITH COLLECT(d) AS domains
UNWIND domains AS d1
UNWIND domains AS d2
WITH d1,d2
WHERE id(d1) < id(d2) and d1.name='google'
MATCH (d1)-[r:domain_join]-(d2)

       //where r.weight is max // I want something like this (I am stuck at this line)

return d1.name,d2.name,r.weight;
```

The output I am getting is [image]

The output I want is the single row having the maximum weight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
return d1.name,d2.name,r.weight
ORDER BY r.weight DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you may be able to simplify your query (especially if you have an index on the name property for your domain nodes). By the way, labels usually start with an uppercase letter and types for relationships are all uppercased.

```
MATCH (google:domain {name: 'google'})
MATCH (google)-[r:domain_join]-(d2:domain)
RETURN d2.name, r.weight
ORDER BY r.weight DESC LIMIT 1
```